# Python post request 418 error

Tags: python, ajax, post, python-requests

I'm trying to use Python post request to automate the refreshing of a summoner profile in OP.GG:

On the page there is a button that calls the following javascript file: 
https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/js3/summoner.js?1492755586

Navigating to this URL: `https://na.op.gg/summoner/userName=hamski`

Running the follow snippet of code in Chrome's console works perfectly. The profile refreshed as expected.

```
$.OP.GG.ajax.getJSON({
    url: ('/summoner/ajax/renew.json/'),
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        summonerId: 47220368
    },
    callback: {
        onJSON: function(json){
            console.log(json)
        },
        onError: function(error){
            $.OP.GG.summoner.renewBtn.stop(btn);
            alert(error);
        }
    }
});
```

I did a post request using the requests module

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://na.op.gg/summoner/ajax/renew.json/"

payload = {
    'summonerId': 47220368,
}

data=json.dumps(payload)

print data

r = requests.post(url, data)

print r
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

The result was a 418 error.

`<Response [418]>
418`

r.text basically gives me the html of this page:
https://na.op.gg/summoner/ajax/renew.json/

---

Updated code:

```
import json
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent(cache=False)


url = "https://na.op.gg/summoner/ajax/renew.json/"

payload = {
    'summonerId': 47220368,
}

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update(
{
    'User-Agent':ua.random
})

print ua.random

session = requests.Session()
r1 = session.get("https://na.op.gg/summoner/userName=hamski",headers=headers )
print session.cookies.get_dict()

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload),cookies=r1.cookies, headers=headers)

print r
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Comment: You have been talking to a teapot. Error code 418 "I'm a teapot" was an aprils fool joke. It seems like the developers had some humor. Your problem should come from the fact that the browser is authenticated already and the Python request is not. Check the network tab of the browser console to see if anything in the request could authenticate it.

Comment: Still not sure what the issue is. Can you elaborate on what you mean by checking the network tab? I added a random user agent to the header along with default headers. I also retrieved cookies from a previous session, and added those in the post request as well. Running the code gets the same result. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out what was missing in my request using a request interceptor - chrome extension called "postman"

Turns out that the cookies and headers did not matter at all.

Replacing data=json.dumps(payload) with data=payload fixed the issue.